# Using ManyToManyRelationship using 'trough'

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 Entities/Models Person and Event.

There is a many to many connection between Person and Event, a Person can participate to multiple events, on an Event multiple Persons are going.

A person is not necessary to participate to an Event, an event can be empty.

I can do this in `Django`:

```
class Person(models.Model):

name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
event = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)
```

This creates a related table with:

```
id | person_id | event_id
```

But I need a person to have more attributes related to Event, besides the keys, like `Person's event number, Person's booth` etc.

In Django documentation I found 'trough' model.

What is not clear(didn't found) is related to create/update/delete using forms so  I need some examples and how querysets work;

Example:

1. In a form I want to select and Event from a list and associated with the Person, and complete in the form the  Person's event number, Person's booth etc.
2. How can I use 1) as a formset, for the user on the same form/page to link multiple events to a Person.
3. If an Event or a Person is deleted, is the 'trough' model record deleted automatically or need to do something manually ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this oughta work.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    events = models.ManyToManyField('Event', through='Attendance')


class Event(models.Model):
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField('Person', through='Attendance')


class Attendance(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='attendances', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, related_name='attendances', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    booth = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

You can then simply create forms/formsets for `Attendance` objects.
You can access an user's events through `p.events.all()`, or their attendances (with those extra infos) through `p.attendances.all()`.
Similarly you can look at all the people attending an event through `e.attendees.all()`, etc.

Since `on_delete=models.CASCADE` is set, the Attendances will disappear when the event or person is deleted.